# Getting runtime error: glCreateProgram is not exported by the available OpenGL driver

Tags: python, arcade

I am running Win 10, DirectX v12 Version 382.05

I copied this from https://realpython.com/arcade-python-game-framework/ . I have installed arcade and psychoPy and dataclasses.

```
def basic_arcade_program():
    # Basic arcade program
    # Displays a white window with a blue circle in the middle
    # Imports
    import arcade

    # Constants
    SCREEN_WIDTH = 600
    SCREEN_HEIGHT = 800
    SCREEN_TITLE = "Welcome to Arcade"
    RADIUS = 150
    # Open the window
    arcade.open_window(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, SCREEN_TITLE)
    # Set the background color
    arcade.set_background_color(arcade.color.WHITE)
    # Clear the screen and start drawing
    arcade.start_render()
    # Draw a blue circle
    arcade.draw_circle_filled(SCREEN_WIDTH / 2, SCREEN_HEIGHT / 2, RADIUS, arcade.color.BLUE)
    # Finish drawing
    arcade.finish_render()
    # Display everything
    arcade.run()    


basic_arcade_program()
```

and I get this error:
[image]

The error originates on this line:

```
arcade.draw_circle_filled(SCREEN_WIDTH / 2, SCREEN_HEIGHT / 2, RADIUS, arcade.color.BLUE)
```

Comment: Are your graphics drivers reasonably up-to-date?

Comment: DirectX v12 Version 382.05

Comment: Might be worth getting the latest openGL drivers, available from https://developer.nvidia.com/opengl-driver